# DataFrame with shared row indexes and shared column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to make a dataframe (?) which visually looks like the following:

[image]

Is it possible using pandas? If so, can anyone suggest me related to that. If not, is that even possible to do in python? If possible, can anyone suggest me anything related to that?

Comment: It can't look _exactly_ like that. You can use [MultiIndexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) to wrap multiple rows/cols, but every individual row/col still needs 1 label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That *exact* layout is not possible in pandas because we need some way to programmatically access the values. Looking at your current table, how would we index the cell containing `2`? It doesn't have a distinct index.

We can technically use [MultiIndexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#multiindex-advanced-indexing) to wrap multiple rows/cols, but every individual row/col still needs a separate label, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 4]])
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Col1'], ['X', 'Y'], [0, 1]])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Col2'], [0, 1]])
#              | Col2  |
#              |-------|
#              | 0 | 1 |
# -------------|---|---|
# Col1 | X | 0 | a | 1 |
#      |   |---|---|---|
#      |   | 1 | b | 2 |
#      |---|---|---|---|
#      | Y | 0 | a | 3 |
#      |   |---|---|---|
#      |   | 1 | b | 4 |
```

But this setup makes it really annoying to access values. For example, here we take a row [cross-section](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) at column 1 to access the cell containing `2`:

```
df.xs(('Col1', 'X', 1))[1]
# 2
```

This is why we normally just use standard wide or long tables with simple row/col indexes, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': list('XXYY'), 'Col2_0': list('abab'), 'Col2_1': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
#    Col1  Col2_0  Col2_1
# 0     X       a       1
# 1     X       b       2
# 2     Y       a       3
# 3     Y       b       4

df.loc[1, 'Col2_1']
# 2
```